# Compare two mysql tables for id not in second list

Tags: mysql

I have two tables employees and enrolled students.

Enrolled students holds data as to which students are enrolled into what courses.

I need to find out what employees are not enrolled into a specific course, I have tried this query and had no luck getting a result.

```
SELECT e.user_id
     , e.full_name
     , es.student 
  FROM employees e
  LEFT
  JOIN enrolled_students es 
    on e.user_id = es.student
 WHERE e.level = 3 
   and es.pid = 40 
   and es.student is NULL
```

After I get the result I will then use PHP to add each student that has not yet been added into the course. Which will be set up as a daily cron job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  The condition on the second second needs to go in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT e.user_id, e.full_name, es.student
FROM employees e LEFT OUTER JOIN
     enrolled_students es 
     ON e.user_id = es.student AND es.pid = 40
WHERE e.level = 3 AND es.student IS NULL ;
```

In your version, `es.pid IS NULL` whenever `es.student IS NULL`.  Hence, it cannot be equal to 40.

I'm not sure why you are selecting `es.student`, because you know it is `NULL`.

Comment: This did not work as intended it is returning results that are not null. it returns all results. What I need to figure out is what employee from the employee list is not currently enrolled in each course... for the one above the pid is 40

Comment: @Josh . . . Perhaps you should ask another question with sample data, desired results, and the logic that you want to accomplish.  I believe this answer addresses the issue that you have with the specific issue in this question.

Comment: Thank you I asked another question.